# Showing image in Datagridview based on a value in another column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a data grid view that loads values from a data table and has three columns.
Col0 is the image ( if there is a file attachment or not ), Col1 is the Subject and Col2 is the Attached File Name (Empty string if no attachment)

I want to link col0 to col2 , whereas if the cell in col2 is an empty string, i get no image in col0, otherwise i get the image already saved.

This is my code so far:

```
{
                    string sqlQueryStr = "SELECT Main_Subject,Main_FileName FROM dbo.Main WHERE Main_Subject like @tb_MainSubject ";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryStr, sc);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tb_MainSubject", "%" + tb_MainSubject.Text + "%");
                    sc.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sc.Close();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        myAdapter.Fill(myTable);
                        // Render data onto the screen
                        dgv_Result.DataSource = myTable;


                    }

                    this.dgv_Result.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
                    this.dgv_Result.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
                    this.dgv_Result.Columns[2].Visible = false;


                }
```

Thank you

Comment: foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Result.Rows)
                    {
                        if(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(""))
                            row.Cells[0].Value = "no"
                        else row.Cells[0].Value = "yes";
    
                    }

This works for text columns, how can i set the value for an image ?

Comment: Does cell[0] contain an asp image tag?
If so you can access it by using something like

Image ctl = Cells[0].FindControl["ctrlName"] as Image;
ctl.ImageSource="";

This is all from memory, but hopefully it steers you in the right direction.

Comment: I have found a way to do it but the problem is i cannot find how to specify the path of an image imported to the library

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you not do something like ctl.ImageUrl = "~/images/myimage.jpg"; 
(The ~ should tell it to start at the root of the site)